# How to preserve image formatting when forwarding?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

My bot cannot preserve the formatting of images when sending them from one channel to another, that is, if the image is hidden under a spoiler, it arrives without it. Is it possible to somehow fix this?

```
async def send_media(message, destination_channel_id):
    try:
        if message.media and isinstance(message.media, (MessageMediaPhoto, MessageMediaDocument)):
            return await client.send_message(destination_channel_id, message.text, file=message.media)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
```

I'm using Telethon 1.33

I would be grateful for any help.